# Optimising the seasonal period in STL (Seasonal Decomposition of Time Series by Loess), when the seasonal period is unknown

Tags: r

I can do a STL for a given seasonal time period:

```
n <- 200
dat1 <- cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE))
data_ts <- ts(dat1, freq =20)
plot(stl(data_ts, "per"))
```

However, I do not know the seasonal time period. How can I determine mathematically which is the best one to use?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/detecting-seasonality/ There are lots of articles online that discuss how to detect seasonality...without seeing your specific data, nobody will be able to tell you what the appropriate period is.  However, I'd start with obvious ones based on context of your question....(year, month, week, day, hour...if political, it might be a four or two year period...etc).  Have you tried plotting your data?  Do they "look" seasonal?

Comment: Thanks. I want to determine the best seasonality mathematically, not by eye.